# How to tell Excel to wait to update a cell (in order to avoid circular reference error)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

**Scenario:** I am using a variable in a calculation, which I will call *fred*. I want to calculate *fred* by dividing the last non-zero entry in column B by that entry's row number.

However, where column B becomes zero depends on column A. And column A depends on the values of *fred* and another value I'll call *george*.

**Problem:** This creates a circular reference error.

**Attempt at a solution:** There is a way to calculate a default value for *fred* that doesn't involve column B, so that's what I've got going on right now. But this default value is only good for the default value of *george*. If I change *george*, I need *fred* to update as well following the setup described above.

I can do this manually by changing the value of *george* and then typing in some constant for *fred* until I get the column B to go to zero at the correct time (i.e. when row times *fred* = value in that row). But I'd rather have this process automated than do a guess and check every time.

**Questions:** I'd like to tell Excel to use the default value for *fred* to calculate columns A and B, just to have some numbers there. THEN I'd like Excel to update *fred* based on the new columns, THEN recalculate those columns (or basically just proceed normally). That way, it doesn't matter if *george* is changed; Excel won't give me a circular reference error.

Is there any way to tell Excel to evaluate a cell once, wait while stuff happens, then evaulate again and proceed normally? In a perfect world, Excel would just update *fred* based on cols. A and B until *fred* became stable, but no matter what I try I can't get it to do this. Would enabling iteration help at all? (I'm trying to avoid enabling it for a separate reason.)

Answer (score 0):

fred, huh?

It is possible and often recommended to turn off automatic spreadsheet calculations, especially in large sheets with complex formulae. One such method is provided at the ["dummies"](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-set-manual-recalculation-mode-in-excel-2016/) web site:

> To put the workbook into manual recalculation mode, you select the
>   Manual option on the Calculation Options’ button on the Formulas tab
>   of the Ribbon (Alt+MXM). After switching to manual recalculation,
>   Excel displays CALCULATE on the status bar whenever you make a change
>   to the worksheet that somehow affects the current values of its
>   formulas. Whenever Excel is in Calculate mode, you need to bring the
>   formulas up-to-date in your worksheets before saving the workbook (as
>   you would do before you print its worksheets).
>
> To recalculate the formulas in a workbook when calculation is manual,
>   press F9 or Ctrl+= (equal sign) or select the Calculate Now button
>   (the one with a picture of a calculator in the upper-right corner of
>   the Calculation group) on the Formulas tab (Alt+MB).

Other links from my search provided the specific justification of avoiding circular reference errors.

Comment: That's not going to stop the circular reference error, since _fred_ depends on col B which depends on col A which depends on _fred_.